# Dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Show that the set $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space on the set $\mathbb{Q}$.

What is dimension of of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

First part is easy. Both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are fields and $\mathbb{R}$ contain $\mathbb{Q}$, hence proved.

Assume the dimension is $n$ and the vector space has the ordered basis $B=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ where $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$. Then for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have exactly one ordered set of rational number $t_i$'s such that $x=x_1t_1+\cdots+x_nt_n$.

Now we define the map

$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q^n}$$

$$f(x)=(t_1,\dots,t_n)\text{ where }x=x_1t_1+\cdots+x_nt_n\,.$$

I think the function $f$ is well defined injective function and by:

> *Theorem*: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an injection and $Y$ is countable, then $X$ is coutable as well.

We reach a contradiction because $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

I'm not sure about the proof. It seems alright but this question was to be supposed a tough one.

Please provide your thoughts about it. If it is wrong please point it out.

Comment: You showed that the basis is not _finite_ but it can be countable or uncountable. Do you see how to decide ? (Hint : countable union of countable set is countable).

Comment: As a related exercise, note that a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space of dimension $\kappa$ has cardinality $\kappa$ when $\kappa$ is infinite. More generally, when both the field and dimension are infinite, the cardinality of the vector space is the max of those two cardinalities.

Comment: you can use `\text{ where }` when being in math statement.

Comment: So you've shown what the dimension isn't.  How do you show what the dimension *is*?

Comment: Cardinal arithmetic has an unusual property that for infinite cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$, $\kappa * \lambda = \kappa + \lambda = max(\kappa, \lambda)$. Can you use this to prove that $dim_\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{R}) = 2^{\aleph_0}$?

Answer (score 5):

Your proof only shows that $\Bbb R$ is not of *finite* dimension over $\Bbb Q$, and by stretching it a bit more, you could even show that it implies that the dimension is not countable.

But being uncountable just means *not countable*. If you were asked how many elements are in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, then "more than one" is not the answer you're expected to give.

To solve the mystery, ask yourself, if $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$, and $B$ is a basis for $V$. How would the cardinality of $B$ relate to the cardinality of $V$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable basis. Let $\mathcal{B}=\{r_{1},r_{2},...\}$ be your basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then Let $\mathcal{B_{n}}=\{r_{1},r_{2},...r_{n}\}$.

Now we can say that $$\mathbb{R}=\text{span}(\mathcal{B})=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{span}(\mathcal{B_{n}})$$.

But let $a\in\text{span}(\mathcal{B_{n})}$ be a real number.

Then $a=\sum_{i=1}^{n}q_{i}r_{i}$.

Then $f: \text{span}(\mathcal{B_{n})}\to \mathbb{Q}^{n}$ given by

$f(a)=(q_{1},q_{2},...,q_{n})^{T}$ is a one-one map.

Hence $\text{span}(\mathcal{B_{n}})$ is countable as $\mathbb{Q}^{n}$ is countable.

And hence $$\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\text{span}(\mathcal{B_{n}})$$ is countable as countable union of countable sets is countable.

This contradicts uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$.